# How to add row to a SQL Server table with uniqueidentifier type column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a row to a SQL Server table called `Customers`.

Here is the table design:

[image]

Here how I try to add a row to the table above:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Id, Name) 
VALUES (1, 'test');
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

As you can see the `ID` column of type `uniqueidentifier`. How do I add a `uniqueidentifier` to the column above?

Comment: USE `NEWID ()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` ..

Comment: Use `NEWID()` instead of `1`

Comment: Let the database generate it for you. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1600/auto-generated-sql-server-keys-with-the-uniqueidentifier-or-identity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `newid()`:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(Id, Name) VALUES (newid(), 1);
```

Note that this would often be done using a `default` value:

```
create table customers (
    id uniqueidentifier default newid(),
    . . .
);
```

For various technical reasons, it is not recommended to make the `uniqueidentifier` column a primary key -- although you can get around some of the problems using `newsequentialid()`..  Instead, make it a unique key and have another key (typically an `identity()` column) as the primary key.

Comment: can you explain why it's not recommended to make the uniqueidentifier as a primary key?

Comment: @JeonsoftFaceBundy . . . Because it is not sequential.  By default, the primary key is used as a clustered index (although you can override this).  That means that every insert requires rearranging the data on the data pages.

Answer (score 3):

The uniqueidentifier data type stores 16-byte binary values that operate as globally unique identifiers (GUIDs).

Example using:

```
insert into customers values('7E3E3BC1-9B15-473C-A45A-46D89689156C', 'Tomas')
insert into customers values(newid(), 'Tomas')
```

See more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx